# wanted to implement s horizontal scroll like netflix in reactjs using react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-redux, netflix

I want to have a horizontal scroll-like Netflix in the react js with an arrow on both ends one scrolling previous items and one scrolling next items. But the movies will be dynamic means they are coming from a database. and their number is not fixed. I tried various ways like using section but as the data is dynamic so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You could use array.map() to create all the elements inside the carrusel. Example: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/beginners-guide-loops-in-react-jsx

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout `react-slick` plugin to handle your case. It has a dynamic slides feature where you can add more slides as per your case.

Also, has actions on moving slide which you can use when to fetch the new set of slides from your database.

Ref: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/dynamic-slides